# 'ValueError : No gradients provided for any variable' in Tensorflow 2.2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers

I am fine-tuning a BERT model from huggingface transformers for Named Entity Recognition Task. The input to the model is a single word and output is a tag of that word. I have created a custom generator function (data_generator) from where I am getting data while training. I have freezed the bert layer in training mode and added some layers on top of it to predict the tag of the given word.

The code is this:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation, Dropout, LSTM, GlobalMaxPool1D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

from transformers import BertTokenizer, TFBertModel, BertConfig

# Load the BERT tokenizer.
print('Loading BERT tokenizer...')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)

bert = 'bert-base-uncased'

config = BertConfig(dropout=0.2, attention_dropout=0.2)
config.output_hidden_states = False
transformer_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(bert, config = config)

input_ids_in = Input(shape=(max_len,), name='input_token', dtype='int32')
input_masks_in = Input(shape=(max_len,), name='masked_token', dtype='int32')
embedding_layer = transformer_model(input_ids_in, attention_mask=input_masks_in)[0]

X = LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)(embedding_layer)
X = GlobalMaxPool1D()(X)
X = Dense(50, activation='relu')(X)
X = Dropout(0.2)(X)
X = Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax')(X)

model = Model(inputs=[input_ids_in, input_masks_in], outputs = X)

for layer in model.layers[:3]:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

train_gen = data_generator(sentences, tags, tag2ix, max_len, number_sent_per_batch)
model.fit(train_gen, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
```

The generator function is this :

```py
# data generator, intended to be used in a call to model.fit_generator()

def data_generator(sentences, tags, tag2ix, max_len, num_samples_per_batch):
    
  X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
  n=0
    
  while 1:
    for i in range(len(sentences)):
      n += 1
        
      encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        
          sentences[i],                      # Sentence to encode.
          add_special_tokens = True, # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
          max_length = max_len,           # Pad & truncate all sentences.
          pad_to_max_length = True,
          return_attention_mask = True,   # Construct attn. masks.
          #return_tensors = 'tf',     
          truncation=True
          )
        
      for idx in encoded_dict['input_ids']:
                    
        #idx = [encoded_dict['input_ids'][j]]
        # Add the encoded sentence to the list.
        idx = pad_sequences([[idx]], maxlen=max_len, padding='post')[0]
        X1.append(idx)

      for att_mask in encoded_dict['attention_mask']:
            
        #att_mask = [encoded_dict['attention_mask'][j]]
        # And its attention mask (simply differentiates padding from non-padding).
        att_mask = pad_sequences([[att_mask]], maxlen=max_len, padding='post')[0]
        X2.append(att_mask)
      
      for k in tags[i]:
            
        out = to_categorical([tag2ix[k]], num_classes=num_labels)[0]
        y.append(out)
            
      if n == num_samples_per_batch:
                    
        yield [[array(X1), array(X2)], array(y)]
        X1, X2, y = list(), list(), list()
        n=0
```

The error I am getting is this :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-a19b18bb0230> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(train_gen, epochs=1, steps_per_epoch=steps, verbose=1)
      2 #, validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=val_steps

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:541 train_step  **
        self.trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1804 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:521 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1219 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['lstm_2/lstm_cell_2/kernel:0', 'lstm_2/lstm_cell_2/recurrent_kernel:0', 'lstm_2/lstm_cell_2/bias:0', 'dense_8/kernel:0', 'dense_8/bias:0', 'dense_9/kernel:0', 'dense_9/bias:0'].
```

I have gone through many links like :

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1511

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27949

and many more.

There are many solutions provided in these github issues but couldn't find the solution of my error. I think mine is an error in the code not in the tensorflow library. That's why I don't know where I am getting wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance.

And I also want to know what is the reason of this error, as I have seen people getting same error on different problems (see above links). I am a beginner in tensorflow, so if you know this please let me know.

Comment: I think your global max pooling layer is wrong, should be: `X = GlobalMaxPool1D()(X)`

Comment: Also, I could be mistaken but `inputs` in the model should not be the BERT input ids, they should be a symbolic tensor of your input data which for text data would be something like `tf.keras.Input(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])` (untested)

Comment: (however since your data generator seems to contain `X, y` pairs you can probably just instantiate the model without any arguments: `tf.keras.Model()`)

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 I have corrected `X = GlobalMaxPool1D()(X)` this. This was a typo error, thanks for pointing it out. I am inputting text data as ids of words and I think dtype is not a probem here. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 I have added the generator function, if you can take a look and maybe find something there faulty. Thanks!

Comment: Is this problem resolved ? I'm experiencing a similar error.